# K8S, fluent-bit & elastic: Tried to parse field as object, but found a concrete value

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logging, kibana

I switched from using fluentd to fluent-bit for ingesting K8S cluster logs into elastic, but now I am getting a lot of those error messages (showing up in kibana, so it works at least partially):

```
[object mapping for [kubernetes.labels.app] \
  tried to parse field [app] as object, \
  but found a concrete value, \
  object mapping for [kubernetes.labels.app] tried to parse field [app] as object, \
  but found a concrete value]
```

I don't really understand what that means, to be honest. I googled myself crazy, but found nothing of value. i imagine elastic expects "more dots below" the `kubernetes.app` keyword, but i fail to see why (is `kubernetes.labels.app` not valid together with `kubernetes.labels.app.kubernetes.io`??)

The closest thing I could come up with is a change of the `kubernetes` "property" in elastic to type `text`, yet I ...

- don't really know if this is the correct solution,
- failed to find out how,
- and would not know how to do this for all *new* `logstash-*` indexes which are automatically created by fluent-bit.

can someone help me out here? I am stuck.

I tried re-indexing into a new index, which at least did not fail, but didn't help (obviously, because the old indexes are still used, naturally). also, i have no clue whether the "new mapping" i created (see [here](https://gist.github.com/flypenguin/c5029c86fa1f673ad28ac1683b73d490#file-new-mapping-k8s-elastic-json)) is correct. my fluent-bit config can be found [in the same gist](https://gist.github.com/flypenguin/c5029c86fa1f673ad28ac1683b73d490#file-fluent-bit-config-conf).

any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your mapping [here](https://gist.github.com/flypenguin/c5029c86fa1f673ad28ac1683b73d490#file-new-mapping-k8s-elastic-json-L115) specifies that the field `kubernetes.labels` is a string, but then you're considering it an object that contains a sub-field `app` (i.e., `kubernetes.labels.app`) and trying to write into it. The dot notation allows you to read from sub-fields, which means that if you're trying to write into `kubernetes.labels.app` you must have a mapping like

```
"kubernetes": {
   "properties": {
      ...
      "labels": {
         "properties": {
            "app": { "type": "keyword" },
            ...
         }
      }
```

Comment: thanks a lot! quick followup question(s): will that solve both cases? "kubernetes.labels.app.is = something " _and_ "kubernetes.labels.app = else"? also, how do i apply this for every index (because they are created daily) ... ?

Comment: any given field can have only one mapping, i.e., `kubernetes.labels.app` is either a text or an object. As for the second question, you may want to look into _index templates_